# Strategy for a global network connection listener

Tags: android

What would be the best strategy to have a network connection listener for my application that it is started when the application starts and closes when the activity exists. Could I use a service in which to register  a PhoneStateListener like this:

```
((TelephonyManager)app.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).listen(PhoneStateListener,
                                      PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE);
```

Comment: For those that stumble onto this old question, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783117/network-listener-android

Answer (score -1):

There is no API nor class available from Android SDK where you can register a listener, and wait for network status changes.

Basically you will need to figure out a solution that fits your project requirements.

I found this solution (from another response) very useful [Network listener Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783117/network-listener-android), basically you create an register a BoradcastReceiver that will be waiting for connectivity changes (via intent-filter).

Comment: I know this is an old question and response, but I think there certainly is an API for listening for network status changes? ConnectivityManager has several broadcasts you can listen for. It can tell you when net states change, and what changes.