# Check the Internet Connectivity in Android

Tags: android, connectivity

I am trying to pull as well as push some data to and from the server via webservice. The mandatory thing that should i have to do is connectivity check. What i have done right now is , i have written a connectivity check code in each activity before it pushes/ pulls the result set from the server. I know its not a best way that i should have to code. Instead this connectivity check should be running some thing like a background , (behind the screens) and alerts the user, when the WIFI / 3G becomes low / goes down.

What is the best way to do so ?

Please let me know know your thoughts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for connectivity changes. A detailed post can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783117/network-listener-android).

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, I went through implementation of that code.But when i tried to show alertdialog instead of toast it shows me an error. I know this should come only within an activity, can you suggest me how to do so ? This alertDialog will contain two buttons like retry and cancel. Once i give retry it will check for the connectivity again or cancel to cancel the dialog.

Comment: Considering this is a completely different issue, I think it would be best to ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Hi i do these way maybe there better

```
private boolean checkInternetConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    // test for connection
    if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        //no conection
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: and i think these is already an answered question try to search fisrt

Comment: Yeah, Thanks a lot. but i want the same to be run as a service or like a broadcastreceiver that runs through out the application from launch to end and checks for the connectivity and intimates me , when it gets down. if you have any ideas on this ,please share...

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context){
        ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if(wifi.isConnected() || mobile.isConnected()){
            // Check for web site       
            try{
                // Create a URL for the desired page
                URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                // Read all the text returned by the server
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                in.close();
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

The method also checks whether a certain website in this case the www.google.com is available. This might be useful as the device might be connected to a WLAN router which has no internet access. In this case `wifi.isConnected()` would also return `true` although no internet is available.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks a lot. but i want the same to be run as a service or like a broadcastreceiver that runs through out the application from launch to end and checks for the connectivity and intimates me , when it gets down. if you have any ideas on this ,please share...

Answer (score 0):

for check internet connection in android..

```
public static boolean isOnline(Activity act) 
     {
         ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)act.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
         NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

     }
```

Comment: Yeah, Thanks a lot. but i want the same to be run as a service or like a broadcastreceiver that runs through out the application from launch to end and checks for the connectivity and intimates me , when it gets down. if you have any ideas on this ,please share...