# Check internet connection throughout my application

Tags: android, android-internet

I'm working on Internet based app,so i need to monitor Internet Connection. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts)

I used this code in on create of mainActivity to check my internet connection it works fine.

```
public boolean isOnline() 
{  
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);  return 
cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

But i need this monitoring should be done through out application.
Where should i use this ? Any AsyncTask needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

create a BroadcastReceiver to detect change in connection status. see Eric's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783117/network-listener-android)

Comment: Thanks Josephus. You mean to say BroadcastReceiver will keep on checking internet connection at back end right?

Comment: no it doesn't. android throws a broadcast when internet connection drops or changes status. you just need to catch that broadcast, so you don't need to check everytime.

Comment: oh its great... Eric's answer was good. but how do i intiaiate this Broadcast Reciever i mean onRevieve method? if i have toggle button to switch on/off Broadcast reciever.?

Comment: As in Eric's code, Broadcast reciever will be running through out application right?

Comment: BroadcastReceiver technically will not be "running throughout" the application, instead it just registers your application to receive the broadcast. It's not an "always alive" service if that's what you're worring about.

Comment: ya really i was worried about battery and performance of my app. thanks Josephus

Comment: What in case the connection does not disconnect but as is typical a case in some not so developer countries the GPRS gets stuck. What will the broadcast return? Or should we use a timeout?

Comment: @NunChai Yes, the only way to handle that would be to use some timeout mechanism. The implementation depends on what library you're using, which can be answered in a separate Question thread.

Answer (score 4):

Use a BroadCast Receiver, like so :

```
private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
            String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
                        boolean isFailover = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);

            NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            NetworkInfo otherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);

            // do application-specific task(s) based on the current network state, such 
            // as enabling queuing of HTTP requests when currentNetworkInfo is connected etc.
        }
    };
```

---

```
 private void registerReceivers() {    
       registerReceiver(mConnReceiver, 
           new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Reno. But i need to know using Broadcast Receiver is efficient because it drains out battery by keep on checking ? or in wat kind of applications use this Broadcast receiver any example?

Comment: @Reno thats spam ..dont click

Comment: @ShivamSharma That blog/url is expired so I have removed it. As for this answer as of now Connectivity change broadbroadcasts are not done in the background in N OS onwards to save power

Comment: @Reno ok .. thanx