# connectivitymanager - android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE

Tags: android, android-intent

I have created an  filter for [`android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION).
I do receive intents to my broadcastreceiver.

My question is regarding what raises the `connectivity_change`. 
The API description says:

> A change in network connectivity has occurred. A connection has either
>   been established or lost. The NetworkInfo for the affected network is
>   sent as an extra; it should be consulted to see what kind of
>   connectivity event occurred.

It seems my broadcastreceiver is only called when mobile network is connected/disconnected (pdp is broken). It is not raised when for example 2g switches to 3g.

Can I not catch  2g to 3g swaps with this broadcastreceiver?
Do I have to use a phonestatelistener instead to catch swaps from e.g, 2g to 3g?

Comment: Check this topic .

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783117/network-listener-android

Comment: The code in that thread looks like what I have done, but it only seems to catch disconnects from mobile networks (and thats also what it looks like the person in that thread was looking for)  , not handover from 2g to 3g

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need:

`permission "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"` //to get connection changes (2G/3G/etc)
`permission "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"` //to get Cell/Tower changes

and

```
//Make the listener
listener = new PhoneStateListener() { 
    public void onDataConnectionStateChanged(int state, int networkType) 
    { 
       //We have changed proticols, for example we have gone from HSDPA to GPRS
       //HSDPA is an example of a 3G connection 
       //GPRS is an example of a 2G connection
    }
    public void onCellLocationChanged(CellLocation location) {
       //We have changed to a different Tower/Cell
    }
};

//Add the listener made above into the telephonyManager
telephonyManager.listen(listener, 
        PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE //connection changes 2G/3G/etc
        | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION       //or tower/cell changes 
);
```

Comment: I  believe you are correct. Seems there are no way to get it with a broadcastreceiver yet.