# Wait until task is completed

Tags: java, android, wifi

I need to wait until android enables wifi ( you can't just "setWifiEnabled(true)" and expect to be enabled instantly). I need proper way to do that.

I have some code and its working, but i don't think its proper way to get job done ( i think )

```
while(wifiManager.getWifiState() != 3) {


            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

I already checked [wait until wifi connected on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678362/wait-until-wifi-connected-on-android) , but i didn't found answer i need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way is to register for wifi connection events.  Then Android will call you when its connected.  See [How to detect when WIFI Connection has been established in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888502/android-wifi-how-to-detect-when-wifi-connection-has-been-established)

Comment: Oh, wish i have found above thread sooner. Thank you for you answer and help.