# Connection 3G vs Wi-Fi Connection

Tags: java, android, http, http-headers

I'm develop a android app that consume a xml webservice. When connected in a wi-fi network works fine, but when connected in a 3G network, fail (http 404 not found).

It's not happening only in device. To make tests, I create a main method in desktop and the problem occurs to. When I connected in Wifi network works and in 3G network fail.

I see the HttpRequest header and his have same information, when in 3g or wifi.

What can be? Help me!!

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 10000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 10000);       

System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);

get.addHeader("Referer", "http://rast.sample.com/sample");
get.addHeader("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.97 Safari/537.22");
get.addHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
get.addHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest11");
get.addHeader("Accept","application/xml, text/xml, */*");
get.addHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); // HTTP/1.1
get.addHeader("Expires", "Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
get.addHeader("Connection","close");

HttpResponse resp = client.execute(get);
HttpEntity entityResp = resp.getEntity();
```

I think that the problem can be 3G cache, how I can clean?

Edit:
I realized that with 3G sometimes works and sometimes not.

I make the following test:
With two devices on 3G, one working and another not. I enable the device was working as Access Point for the device that not working (share the 3G network of working device) then the other device work too.

Edit2: 
I realized that navigating the site, connected to the 3G network, it works. What can it be?

Comment: Do you get any response? Some mobile operators are trying to "optimize" anything that looks like HTML and break XML in the process. Try HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a problem due to the fact that the connection is not established yet...

Try something like waiting for connection as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8679706/944070

would also work for 3G

**Edit:**

After your extra code I would also suggest changing timeout to from `10000` to `45000` or `60000` 3G is always slower than wifi!

**Edit 2:** elaboration of [wait until wifi connected on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678362/wait-until-wifi-connected-on-android) link.

change your code like:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //check if connected!
            int count = 0;
            while (!isConnected(YourActivityName.this)) {
                count++;
                //Wait to connect
                Thread.sleep(1000);  
                // log to help you understand what is going on...
                Log.w("debug", "no connection try "+ count); // ... do not forget to remove it!
                // DO NOT TRY FOR EVER!!!
                if(count > Number_of_allowed_times) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(isConnected(YourActivityName.this)) {
               Log.w("debug", "network connection OK! ");
               // here you can do your stuff
            } else {
               Log.w("debug", "no connection tried " + count +" times");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
};
t.start();
```

`isConnected` is just like the at the link:

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = null;
    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    }

    return networkInfo == null ? false : networkInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED;
}
```

Instead of Thread and wait you can use a `BroadcastReceiver` for `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` and when connection established get notified to refresh/download content.

Comment: Can be 3G cache? I received a response before the timeout expire, so I don't think the problem is here.

Comment: can you log at the server-side? Is your request reaching the server?

Comment: I suspect of any cache of android or 3G. I try use a sniffer in pc to see the 3G traffic, but is not the same of device traffic. Exists one sniffer for android device?

Comment: I dont have a server-side log.

Comment: again have you tested to change the timeout??? or try to change the working SIM with the not working SIM between the two devices! Are both devices same OS, same manufacturer?

Comment: Also found that: http://android-developers.blogspot.gr/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html if it is helpful...

Comment: I realized that navigating the site, connected to the 3G network, it works. What can it be?

Comment: then try to implement a wait for connection in order for 3g to connect... check out the url that I had already posted

Comment: I make tests with HttpUrlConnection and the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and then post the results