# How to progress dialog while wifi connect

Tags: android

I have a little problem on android.

If I take a different action when a WI-FI Connecting 
app is stopped

So, I think while WI-FI Connecting , showing progress dialog.
but I had searched failed
How can I programming?

this is connect button listener

```
private OnClickListener mConnectOnClick = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final WifiConfiguration config = Wifi.getWifiConfiguration(mWifiManager, mScanResult, mScanResultSecurity);
        boolean connResult = false;
        if(config != null) {
            connResult = Wifi.connectToConfiguredNetwork(mFloating, mWifiManager, config, false);
        }
        if(!connResult) {
            Toast.makeText(mFloating, R.string.toastFailed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        mFloating.finish();
    }
};
```

mFloating , wifi connect dialog class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wait until wifi connected on android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678362/wait-until-wifi-connected-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

// First Check internet NetWork

```
if (UIUtils.checkNetwork(v.getContext())) {


                    //Call toDo Task Function

                       toDoTaskFunction();

                } else {

                    UIUtils.showToast(v.getContext(), v.getContext().getString(R.string.no_internet_message));

  }

private void toDoTaskFunction() {

        // Call Dialog Box

            UIUtils.showDialog(AccountActivity.this);

        // After Commpleted Your Process or Any Method

            UIUtils.dismissDialog();

    }
```

Comment: thanks for answer. but previous answer isOnline class.