# How to catch an Exception if the Internet or Signal is down

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i am working with mediaplayer and streaming audio and i am wondering what is the best way to catch an excpetion if the internet or signal is down and can not stream anymore audio.

below is my code that i have done so far, as you can see i am throwing all the excpetion with same message.

```
private class taskDoSomething extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Employee>> 
{ 

    @Override 
    protected List<Employee> doInBackground(Void... params) 
    { 
    String url = "http://ofertaweb.ro/android/sleepandlovemusic/list_files.php";

    try {
        Get_Webpage obj = new Get_Webpage(url);
        directory_listings = obj.get_webpage_source();
    } catch (Exception e) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "You have to be connected to the internet for this application to work", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: This question will help with the connection test -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts

Comment: Are yo using a webview or something?

Comment: Yo can use Volley if what you intend to do is fetch a request because volley handles network exceptions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

its not a exception but it checks the connection

```
public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: this works fine but i think he intended to know if the connection goes down while in the middle of a transaction.

Comment: This will also require you to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` to your manifest as well.

Answer (score 3):

You should use Broadcast receiver and listen to the broadcast changes.

You can find the entire code here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1785300/563306