# Pop-up for No Internet Connection in Android App

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I use Firebase in My Android App for Login & Registering. My Login Page is My Launcher Activity. I want if user is not connected to Internet or WiFi it's Shows the pop-up of No Internet Connection. How to Achieve It ?

Comment: if you are using retrofit in onfialure method put the dailog inside it

Answer (score 0):

You can use this answer : [How to catch an Exception if the Internet or Signal is down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521232/how-to-catch-an-exception-if-the-internet-or-signal-is-down)

Or check result / put try - catch around `GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);`

Comment: the answer in the url  work even the no internet services

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out) question to detect if internet is connected. 
If no, use [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) (or any other "pop-ups") to show message to user.