# how to treat internet connection issue in android

Tags: android

I've researched most of the questions here but did not find a viable solution.

I'm designing an app that highly uses internet connection. I permanently need to request/receive information from a web service.

I've tried sourounding all code that uses internet with

```
    try
    {
       //use of internet here
    }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
          //Alert dialog that states internet connection is down
   }
```

but this doesn't seem to work. The exception is not catched here for some reason.

I've tried a workaround, a solution i found here. Use of:

```
 public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And use it like :

```
        if (Utilities.IsOnline(context))
         {
          //Code that uses internet
         }
```

What happens if the connection is lost right after the IsOnline check?
How can i treat this case?
Thank you!

Comment: Consider how your network connection is affecting the battery life of your application. If you are using the network heavily, it is worth taking a look at the ARO tool that will show you if you are caching data correctly, it could make a big difference to the performance of your application http://developer.att.com/aro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to check if the internet went down after your `isOnline` check is to register a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) that listens to network connection changes. There is a full-code example of that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783117/network-listener-android).

I would suggest, if you are not already doing this, is running your code in an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) so it can run its own loop (or series of statements) and check the connection status each loop/iteration/computation and stop if disconnected.