# Android: detect whether the cellular antenna the phone is connected to has changed

Tags: android

I'd like to calculate the following number:

```
CellularServiceChangeRate
```

Wich indicates how frequently the cellular service the user is connected to changes over a certain period of time.

I'm having some trouble in finding a good Event in the `android.telephony` API to listen to which would permit me to determine if:

```
lastAntenna != currentAntenna.
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to determine this?

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a Listener for connection change and save the last known cell network in sharedPreferences or save it to the local database

```
<receiver android="YourNetworkListener">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
```

Check the previous connection with

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("name",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String connection = sharedPref.getString("phone_connection", null);
```

Compare it with the current connection and do the math for your variable and then

Save it

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("name",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
    prefEditor.putString("phone_connection", How Ever You want to identify the networks);
    prefEditor.commit();
```

Comment: thanks! this has led me to the right path. this question gives also more details about how to react to the broadcast event:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783117/network-listener-android

Comment: (too bad there is no listener interface as in with many other sensors)