# Android: Listening and fire the App anytime device connect to internet

Tags: android, notifications

I want my app to be fire any time device connected to internet to pars xml and notify user in notification panel.
Plz let me know how to do .

Answer (score 1):

You need a broadcast receiver to be notified when the internet connection state is changed. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783117/network-listener-android) and [this](http://www.androidsnippets.com/connectivityreceiver).