# Refresh any UI when connection is back

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to refresh my UI when connection is established. While there is no connection, app shows a boring spinning dialog. When connection is back, it remains same. I just want to refresh my view in every aspect of my application. How can i implement such code that can be used in every activity, every fragment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Broadcast receiver for checking internet connection in android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app)

Comment: checked that question. im already using those in my application. i just want a code that restarts my activity or fragment or such logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using [Broadcast Receivers](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html) and the `invalidate()` method of the desired view you want to refresh. I'll leave the rest to you

```
ViewGroup vg = findViewById (R.id.mainLayout); // Any View you'd like to refresh
vg.invalidate(); // Refresh your view.
```

Another example found here in S.O.: [Network listener Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783117/network-listener-android)

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: If you're not willing to cooperate and research a solution for your problem, then no explanation is to be given, right? @shkschneider mentioned Broadcast Receivers and you asked a code that restarts your activity or your fragment. It's not recommended to restart your activity just to refresh a single view. Instead, you create a ConnectivityManager and listen to its notifications. When you receive a notification that your cellphone has connectivity, you call the `invalidate()` method of the view you want to refresh.

Comment: Thank god finally an explanation

Comment: By the way, remember to upvote the answer that helped you :)