# Refresh activity if Internet connection established in between task is running

Tags: android

I am getting data from the server using retrofit and showing it on the
fragmented screen. But when the internet is not there no data will be available. When I on the net connection will app is on, data is not loading as the activity is not refreshing. So I'm thinking of refreshing page by pull down. If u have a better idea, you are well come to share.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use BroadcastReciever class for detecting Network changes.

You may get a solution here:
[Network listener Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783117/network-listener-android)